# ajax, jquery and html5 sound

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, audio

so I have very little experience in javascript, jquery or ajax but it seems I need all these things to accomplish what I want to do.

I have a website that gets a full body replacement every minute. within the body is a single html5 audio tag like this:

```
<audio id='sound'>
  <source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

once the full body gets refreshed via the jquery, ajax script below I want to play that audio tag.

so I thought I set 2 functions, 1 which reloads the site and 1 which plays the sound. However this doesnt work as ajax is asynchronous. the sound gets played before a refresh.

I have been reading and it seems I need callbacks to do what I want. But through the soup of me having little knowledge of either javascript, jquery and ajax I am just lost..

I have to use a refresh like this because I don`t want to ever end in a site not found or something like that because of a connection error.

Also it seems to me that my full body replacement could use some work as using a regex like that seems rather excessive.

the last connect block is just a small colored block where I can see what was the last state of the website.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function update_site() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/test",
            dataType: "html",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                // Replace body with loaded site. You can do more checks here to check
                // if the fetched content is all there.
                var body_html = data.replace(/^[\S\s]*<body[^>]*?>/i, "")
                        .replace(/<\/body[\S\s]*$/i, "");
                $('body').html(body_html);
                $('.last_connect').css('background-color', 'blue');
            }, 
            error: function(data) {
                $('.last_connect').css('background-color', 'red');
            }
        });
    }
    function play_snd() {
        $('.last_connect').css('background-color', 'yellow');
        $('#sound').trigger("play");
    }
// Run every 20 secs.
window.setInterval(function() {
    update_site();
    play_snd();
}, 4000);
</script>
```

Comment: yeah I know they are different just a typo, fixed now

Comment: OK, fair enough. Again, best of luck!

Comment: Why not put your `play_snd()` inside `success` callback of `ajax` request instead of `setInterval` callback? What's inside that data that you pass every time? Do you control it? Why not add a sound 1 time and then just check some single server function to make sure it's alive and if it is - play that sound?

Comment: the entire body is in the data. its just some standard html data. the only thing that is more advanced is the audio tag as mentioned. I control it as the backend is a python flask server. the sound can differ on the next refresh. If there is a way to get a single variable from the server via jquery and then use that directly to play the sound that would work too. How would something like that work?